# Rundeck server with Internet clients

Tags: ssh, rundeck

I recently started evaluating Rundeck for our runbook automation needs. However I found that it works on SSH based connection method and our endpoints where we want to perform automation is in our customer locations. So I was hoping that it has an agent which we will install on those Windows 10 IoT based endpoints and then perform the runbook automation task remotely, but it appears that there is no agent for Rundeck.

Anyone made it work with such arrangements?

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck is an agentless solution, for Windows based machines/servers Rundeck uses the PyWinRM (Python [WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/portal)) [plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin) out of the box. Check the [requirements](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#requirements), [configuration](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#configuration), [node definition](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#node-definition-example) and a [good](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/77I-HjrKBew/m/5Xu6-NWUAwAJ) job example.

Comment: thanks. Will not work in my use cases as all the clients are out in the field all over the globe